# what is the solution to this problem "failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED http://localhost:8989/route?....."

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, localhost, gis

I have a problem with my program. this is a program about geographic information system that uses the LeatlefJs library, I also use the letlef routing machine feature. the problem is the system can't display the route it should be able to display, I don't really understand. this is the script.

```
        function getDirectRoute(index, callbackFunction){
            var dari = marker_awal.getLatLng().lat + "," + marker_awal.getLatLng().lng;
            var tujuan = markerCabang[index].getLatLng().lat + "," + markerCabang[index].getLatLng().lng;
            $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "http://localhost:8989/route?point=" + dari + "&point=" + tujuan + "&points_encoded=false&instructions=false&vehicle=motorcycle&ch.disable=true&weighting=shortest&algorithm=alternative_route",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  contentType: "application/json",
                  success: function (data) {
                    successReveived++;
                    var coordinates = data.paths[0].points.coordinates;
                    tempDistance = 0;      
                    for(var j=0; j<coordinates.length; j++){
                        if(j==0){
                            tempDistance += euclidean(marker_awal.getLatLng().lat, marker_awal.getLatLng().lng, coordinates[j][1], coordinates[j][0]);
                        } else {
                            tempDistance += euclidean(coordinates[j-1][1], coordinates[j-1][0], coordinates[j][1], coordinates[j][0]);
                        }
                    }
                    distanceGH[index] = data.paths[0].distance;
                    distanceManual[index] = tempDistance.toFixed(4);
                    
                    if(successReveived == markerCabang.length && typeof(callbackFunction == 'function')){
                        callbackFunction();
                    }
                  }
            });
        }
```

the error is like this

failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED http://localhost:8989/route?point=3.611967691620835,98.67254734039308&point=3.611126,98.67548&points_encoded=false&instructions=false&vehicle=motorcycle&ch.disable=true&weighting=shortest&algorithm=alternative_route

Comment: Please read [Is English required on stack overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow/13684#13684)  (tl;dr: It is). Other language versions of SO are available. Note to other SO users: [Do not translate this on behalf of the OP, if they can't ask the question in English, then they will struggle to respond to comments and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/19068).

Comment: okay. I have changed it to English

Comment: Why do you expect a connection to be accepted on localhost:8989?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just following someone else's script but when I apply it to my program why doesn't it work?

Comment: Because either you missed a major step in the script when reading it or the person who wrote it omitted something (probably because they thought it was obvious).

Comment: is the problem with this connection localhost:8989?

Comment: That's what the error message says

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice and input. my problem is solved. the error is in the port. my port number is http://localhost:80443/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I cannot comment yet, so trying to help you with an answer)

1. Make sure you have a working valid backend to respond for the JS library (see https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/alternative-routers/ for valid backends)
2. Try entering the URL directly in your browser (without Leaflet or anything else): http://localhost:8989/route -> You should see JSON output, even if it says malformed or invalid request. If you are having the network issue here already you need to check the network layer (e.g. firewalls, port binding of the backend etc.), continue if thats not the case.
3. Open the network tab in your browsers DEV tools (F12) and filter all connections to your backend. Now try the map / leafletJS and check for additional information in that tab. You might see an error that your browser blocked the request due to something related to Cross-Origin-Requests (CORS).

Comment: thank you very much for the advice. my problem is solved. the error is in the port. my port number is http://localhost:80443/